# Reinterpret cast on *shared memory*

Tags: glsl, vulkan, gpgpu, reinterpret-cast, gpu-shared-memory

I have a fairly large object that I want to load into shared memory so that multiple warps can access the object, something like

```
struct alignas(8) Foo{
   int a;
   float b; 
   vec2 c; 
   uvec2 d; 
   uint64_t e; 
....
}
```

In CUDA, I'd handle loading this object in by *reinterpreting* the data as something else with the same alignment, and putting that into shared memory.

```
__global__ void bar(const Foo * global_foo_ptr){
    __shared__ Foo shared_foo; 
    int tid =  blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int threads_per_block = blockDim.x; 
    
    auto reinterpreted_shared_foo_ptr = reinterpret_cast<std::uint64_t*>(&shared_foo); 
    auto reinterpreted_global_foo_ptr = reinterpret_cast<std::uint64_t*>(global_foo_ptr);
    
    for(int i = tid; i < sizeof(Foo) / sizeof(std::uint64_t); i += threads_per_block ){
        reinterpreted_shared_foo_ptr[i] = reinterpreted_global_foo_ptr[i];
    } 
}
```

which allows coalesced reads which threads can participate in parallel.

But I don't know how to do the same in Vulkan GLSL, I can't find a "reinterpret" cast function in Vulkan, though [buffer_reference_2 I think has this capability on the *global memory side*](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/GLSL/blob/main/extensions/ext/GLSL_EXT_buffer_reference2.txt) only.

Answer (score 3):

GLSL doesn't let you do low-level stuff like that. And I'm not sure you can do it through SPIR-V directly either.

SPIR-V allows something like this [through `OpBitcast`](https://registry.khronos.org/SPIR-V/specs/unified1/SPIRV.html#OpBitcast). However, this requires that the pointers involved use physical addressing. And while storage buffers can be set to use physical addressing (if the implementation allows it), I don't see anything that would allow the `Workgroup` storage class (the SPIR-V equivalent to `shared`) to use physical addressing.